# How to determine, in a Moose constructor, what context it was called in?

Tags: perl, moose

Let's say we have a Moose class like so:

```
package My::Test ;
use Moose ;
$\="\n";

sub BUILDARGS {
    my ($pkg,%args) = @_ ;
    print defined wantarray ? 'BUILDARGS: SCALAR':'BUILDARGS: VOID' ;
    return \%args ;
}

sub BUILD {
    print defined wantarray ? 'BUILD: SCALAR':'BUILD: VOID' ;
    my ( $self, $args ) = @_ ;
    print '---' ;
}
1;
```

Instantiating the class in both SCALAR and VOID context I get always the same output:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Moose ;
use My::Test ;
# Scalar ctx
my $instance = My::Test->new ;
# Void ctx
My::Test->new ;
```

Output:

```
BUILDARGS: SCALAR
BUILD: VOID
---
BUILDARGS: SCALAR
BUILD: VOID
```

I was able to get the context wrapping the Moose class instance creation  in a trivial package and passing the context as constructor attribute as follows:

```
package My::Wrapper ;
use My::Test ;
sub new {
    my ( $class , %args ) = @_ ;
    return My::Test->new(%args , ctx => defined wantarray ? 'scalar':'void') ;
} 
1 ;
```

but I would like to know if there is a cleaner way for doing that.

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: It's not a strong requirement...  anyway: I'm writing a WebSocket multiplexer, and in my API design , in VOID context the sockets loop is started at instance creation, otherwise in SCALAR context not, enabling the instance consumer to access to instance methods and control the multiplexer initialization flow.. a kind of dummy or expert mode.

Comment: That's not a good idea. It makes for a very bad interface. And just so you can do `Foo->new(...);` instead of `Foo->new(...)->run;`? Just don't.

Comment: @ikegami it's because I'm a fan of the "write less do more" approach.. but you're right, in this case it can be ambiguous.

Comment: But you're also gaining surprise/fragility. And avoid just 4 characters once per program is not really writing less. What could do to achieve your goal is to make `->run` accept a class as well as an object as an invocant (`sub run { my $self = shift; $self = $self->new(@_) if !ref($self); ... }`).

Comment: Well @ikegami.. after a few beers I did as you say .. `->new` for expert mode and `->run` for lazy mode, that's definitely a clean and not ambiguous approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Moose creates the constructor for you (see [here](https://metacpan.org/source/Moose::Object#L18)). The context isn't propagated to either BUILDARGS or BUILD.

You can wrap `new` in the Moose way, though:

```
around new => sub {
    my ($orig, $self) = splice @_, 0, 2;
    warn defined wantarray ? 'other' : 'void';
    $self->$orig(@_)
};
```

Comment: Great!I hadn't thought about method modifiers.. Thanks!